# Using Titanium with Windows Azure

Tags: azure, titanium, azure-storage

I want to integrate Windows Azure Services within the app created in Titanium, same as we use to do with eclipse for Android. I am newbie working with Titanium. Please help me providing some useful links to get started with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these:
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149494/using-titanium-httpclient-to-access-windows-azure-mobile-services-rest-api

Since this is a JavaScript library, it should help.  It may be a bit old though.
http://azureblobstoragejs.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you provide me some more info on how to connect to azure database using javascript, as i will be working with Titanium Alloy. Please help me. Trying since the day i questioned on SO, but didn't found any solution.

Comment: Even went through your links but found no solution.

Comment: Heyy sir. i did it using your first link of windows azure mobile services REST api. Thank you so much. And One thing i wanted to ask is that, is there any need to create web services if we want to work with azure database ?? Check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017073/azure-whether-to-create-web-services-or-not

Answer (score 1):

This is how i got the data using REST API.

```
function getWebserviceURL() {

    return "https://database_name.azure-mobile.net/tables/";
}

function getCountryMasterData() {

    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onerror = function(e)
    {
        alert(e.toString);
    };
    xhr.onload = function() {
        alert(this.responseText);
    };
    var request_url = getWebserviceURL() + "table_name";
    xhr.open('GET', request_url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", "APP KEY");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Host", "database_name.azure-mobile.net");
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: This should probably be the answer shree, I was just throwing out some potential links to help.  Thanks for sharing. I had not tried connecting to Azure before.

Comment: @Martin Its alright sir. Though, your link carried major potential, through which i was able to make it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I wrote a Titanium SDK for Windows Azure Mobile Services. Check it out here: https://github.com/rfaisal/tiny-azuresdk-titanium

**Original Answer:**

First login to facebook to get the access_token (let's call it authorization_grant):

```
var fb=require('facebook');
fb.appid = 000000000000000; //replace this with your facebook app id
fb.permissions = ['email']; // add or remove permissions
fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        Ti.API.info('authorization_grant: '+fb.getAccessToken()); // prints to console, save for future use
    }
});
fb.authorize();
```

Then, get access_token (not facebook, but azure) from authorization_grant:

```
var authorization_grant = 'CAAHn34BO0R0BABtJyxdrZCQzakdmgJZBoQa0U...'; //saved from previous step
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.setTimeout(30000);
xhr.onload=function() {
    Ti.API.info('access_token: '+JSON.parse(this.responseText).authenticationToken); // save this for requesting protected resource
};
xhr.onerror= function() {
    Ti.API.info('Auth Failure response: '+this.responseText);
};
xhr.open('POST', 'https://my_resource_auth_server.azure-mobile.net/login/facebook');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.send({
    "access_token" : authorization_grant
});
```

Finally, get the protected resource by access_token:

```
var access_token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsI...'; //saved from previous step
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.setTimeout(30000);
xhr.onload=function() {
    Ti.API.info('Protected Resource: '+this.responseText);
};
xhr.onerror= function() {
    Ti.API.info('Error response: '+this.responseText);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'https://my_resource_auth_server.azure-mobile.net/api/some_resource');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-ZUMO-AUTH", access_token); // this is the magic line
xhr.send();
```

To get resource that require application level access, add a header called X-ZUMO-APPLICATION and pass your Application Key obtained from Azure website. Similarly, to access resource that requires admin level access, pass your Mobile Service master key obtained from Azure website as X-ZUMO-MASTER header.

The oAuth flow being followed here:
[image]

The originally publish article: https://rfaisalblog.wordpress.com/2014/03/01/oauth-flow-for-mobile-apps-with-an-external-identity-server/